# How to smoothly switch to another application window with c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, vlc

This is the code I'm currently using to switch from one window to another

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);

var procList = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

        if(procList.Length > 0)
        {
            ShowWindow(procList[0].MainWindowHandle, 9);
            SetForegroundWindow(procList[0].MainWindowHandle);

            SendMessage(procList[0].MainWindowHandle, 0x0112, 0xF120, 0);
        }
```

The idea is that two other programs are switched back and forth based on certain events, and this works perfectly on my Windows 8.1 debug environment, but on the production machine (Windows 7 Ultimate) it does work, however there is a flicker of blue (presumably from the window's title bar)

Both applications are in maximised windowed mode, and the one that produces the flickering is VLC media player running in quiet remote mode.

Does anybody know a way of smoothly switching these windows that won't produce that flickering effect? It seems to be fine on Windows 8.1 in the debug environment.